# How to create a dictionary and store values of multiple columns w.r.t to one column and reconstruct it back to original dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

Hello I have a dataframe,

```
---------------------
ID | PARTY | KId
---------------------
1  | IND   | 12
2  | IND   | 13
3  | CUST  | 14
4  | IND   | 17
---------------------
```

I want to create a dict in python that stores the values of column 'Party' and 'KId' w.r.t the value in Id.

So my dictionary should be like:

```
dict = {
1 : 'IND_12',
2 : 'IND_13'
.
.

}
```

what I tried:

```
dict = {}
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
for idx in df_.index:
    temp = df[df.index==idx]
    dict[temp['ID'].iloc[0]] = f"{temp['PARTY'].iloc[0]}_{temp['KId'].iloc[0]}"
```

after this dictionary is generated which posiibly is the best solution to reconstruct my original df from the dict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use `dict` for variable, because python code word.

Solution if `ID` is column:

You can jojn both columns and convert it to `dict`:

```
df['PARTY'] = df['PARTY'] + '_' + df['KId'].astype(str)

d = df.set_index('ID')['PARTY'].to_dict()
```

Or:

```
df['PARTY'] = df['PARTY'] + '_' + df['KId'].astype(str)

#failed if dict is variable used before
d = dict(zip(df['ID'], df['PARTY']))
```

Solution if `ID` is index use [`Series.str.cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```
d = df['PARTY'].str.cat(df['KId'].astype(str), sep='_').to_dict()
print (d)
{1: 'IND_12', 2: 'IND_13', 3: 'CUST_14', 4: 'IND_17'}
```

---

For convert back use:

```
d = {1: 'IND_12', 2: 'IND_13', 3: 'CUST_14', 4: 'IND_17'}
    
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index', columns=['PARTY'])

df[['PARTY','KId']] = df['PARTY'].str.split('_', expand=True)
df['KId'] = df['KId'].astype(int)
df = df.rename_axis('ID')
print (df)
   PARTY  KId
ID           
1    IND   12
2    IND   13
3   CUST   14
4    IND   17
```

Comment: how can I regenerate my dataframe back from the dict 'd'?

Comment: @MurtazaBasu - Use `df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')`

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
```

Just make use of `astype()` method and `to_dict()` method:-

```
mydict=(df['PARTY']+'_'+df['KId'].astype(str)).to_dict()
```

For making it back to dataframe use this:-

```
df=pd.DataFrame(mydict.values(),index=mydict.keys())
df=df[0].str.split('_',expand=True).rename(columns={0:'PARTY',1:'KId'})
df['KId']=df['KId'].astype(int)
df.index.name='ID'
```

Comment: how can I regenerate my dataframe back from the dict ?

Comment: Edited my answer...kindly have a look